# Intermittent SSL error when uploading photos using Facebook Android SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Android SDK 3.0 to upload a photo to my album. Everything works, but sometimes the first upload fails with a somewhat unexpected SSL error.

See function `toHttpConnection` in [Request.java](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/Request.java).

```
try {
        connection = createConnection(url);

        serializeToUrlConnection(requests, connection);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR ORIGINATES FROM!
        throw new FacebookException("could not construct request body", e);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new FacebookException("could not construct request body", e);
    }
```

Hovering `e` in Eclipse shows this information:

*javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x4f033008: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x4f033008: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
Write error: ssl=0x4f033008: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
[1277468208, 0, 1279934152, 48, 1280860304, 26, 1280860480, 58, 1280859576, 11, 1280859696, 4, 1277492792, 1, 1280859640, 7, 1280233152, 169, 1280233264, 36, 1280230744, 6, 1280236632, 0, 1280236576, 0, 1280238568, 6, 1280238512, 2, 1278731744, 21, 1279835640, 23, 1278097880, 2, 1279841920, 28, 1279843376, 2, 1277300032, 6]
null*

Is this a bug in the SDK? Did anybody else encounter this? And more importantly, how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm encountering this.  Have you found a solution?  How are you making the request?

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution.

Comment: I've also created a question; I believe I'm seeing the same problem as you but I've provided a bit more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15144102/758458

Answer (score 3):

I was *almost* ready to settle for my previous (removed) answer, until I came across this article: http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/

I decided to give it a shot, and it seems to work!  Here's my code:

```
for (Bitmap b : bitmaps) {
    // id is just a string
    String response = executeUpload(b, id);

    // do something with the response
}

private String executeUpload(Bitmap b, String id) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos");
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 3000);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(2, true));

    ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, id + ".png");
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    reqEntity.addPart("access_token", new StringBody(activeFacebookAccessToken));
    reqEntity.addPart("message", new StringBody(""));
    reqEntity.addPart("picture", bab);
    postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    String s;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder = builder.append(s);
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

As discussed in the link above, you must install the latest `HttpClient` (found at http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi).

Another important thing to note is that Facebook supports a maximum image size of 720 px in either dimension.  In my code I'm scaling the bitmap to be within that size limit before doing the upload which greatly improves performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem here is that Facebook SDK 3.0 is being used. Using the SDK has many advantages, but uploading images has this weird _sporadic_ problem. We need to find out where the error comes from. Is it the Facebook SDK or is it the underlying HTTP library (i.e. Java/Android)? Uploading images using the Facebook SDK works too, but not always.

Comment: The problem is occurring in `HttpURLConnection` which the Facebook SDK is using to make the `POST` call.  My solution uses the `Apache` HTTP client instead which does not have this problem.  I also updated my answer to add retry on error.

Comment: So the ultimate solution is to modify the Facebook SDK to use the Apache HTTP client instead?

Comment: Have fun digging through the chains of method calls to get to the actual HTTP call.  It's a bit extreme.

Comment: The info about facebook max image size of 720x720 solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

@i33t: I had faced the same problem with IoException and FacebookException.. 
in my case the problem was with running network operation on UI thread..

if you actually print the stacktrace you will get this.

**Solution:** make sure to perform this **operation on WorkerThread**

Comment: I believe Android 4+ doesn't even allow network operations on the UI thread. What you are saying makes perfect sense. However, I haven't seen this error since I upgraded to `Facebook SDK` **3.0.1**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running to this problem.
My Facebook SDK version is 3.5.2. And this problem can only be reproduced on Samsung Note2 with 4.3 os version.

This problem acts very weird because it acting as succeed once, failed once then succeed once, failed once..

The cause exception message are below:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x59b399c8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x5d887c58:0x00000000)
```