# Error uploading photos using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

This is a similar problem to [Intermittent SSL error when uploading photos using Facebook Android SDK 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14162223/758458) but that question has no responses and I'd like to provide more detail in the question.

I'm attempting to upload photos to a user's Facebook account using the following code:

```
ArrayList<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
for (String id : ids) {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
    Bitmap b;
    try {
        b = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error uploading photo to facebook", e);
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error uploading photo to facebook", e);
        return;
    }
    if (b != null) {
        requests.add(Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(FacebookLoginHelper.getInstance().getActiveSession(), b,
                null));
    }
}
List<Response> responses = Request.executeBatchAndWait(requests);
for (Response response : responses) {
    if (response.getError() == null) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Successfully uploaded image");
    } else {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Error uploading image: " + response.getError().getErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
02-28 11:26:52.936: W/System.err(5848): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error:        ssl=0x72be0428: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
02-28 11:26:52.936: W/System.err(5848):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
02-28 11:26:52.936: W/System.err(5848):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:706)
02-28 11:26:52.936: W/System.err(5848):     at libcore.net.http.ChunkedOutputStream.writeHex(ChunkedOutputStream.java:102)
02-28 11:26:52.936: W/System.err(5848):     at libcore.net.http.ChunkedOutputStream.writeBufferedChunkToSocket(ChunkedOutputStream.java:128)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at libcore.net.http.ChunkedOutputStream.write(ChunkedOutputStream.java:77)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:185)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:139)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCompress(Native Method)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:875)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at com.facebook.Request$Serializer.writeBitmap(Request.java:1688)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at com.facebook.Request$Serializer.writeObject(Request.java:1666)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at com.facebook.Request.serializeAttachments(Request.java:1569)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at com.facebook.Request.serializeToUrlConnection(Request.java:1467)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at com.facebook.Request.toHttpConnection(Request.java:933)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(Request.java:1027)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(Request.java:1003)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at com.mycompany.mypackage.services.FacebookPhotoUploadService.onHandleIntent(FacebookPhotoUploadService.java:50)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/System.err(5848):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
02-28 11:26:52.946: D/skia(5848): ------- write threw an exception
02-28 11:26:52.946: W/com.mycompany.mypackage.services.FacebookPhotoUploadService(5848): Error uploading image: com.facebook.FacebookException: could not construct request body
```

Things I'm sure of:

- the bitmap I'm sending in the request is valid
- I'm properly logged into Facebook with an active session

I was able to get this to work successfully twice out of about 15 or 20 tries (verified by going to Facebook in my browser and seeing the image there).

I don't think it's important, but this is happening in the `onHandleIntent()` method of an `IntentService`.

Comment: I just had the same thing happen to me. It looks like the image didn't upload for me either, even though the request took a decent amount of time as if it was uploading successfully. I'm interested to see what the issue is.

Comment: I ended up rewriting my service to use deprecated Facebook SDK calls: `new Facebook("appID").request("me/photos", params, "POST")` which WORKS but its not ideal.  I don't understand why it works though because the underlying POST call is the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: Could it have something to do with this? `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "false");`

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8625 Does the suggested fix solve the problem?

Comment: AndroidHttpClient doesn't support writing to an OutputStream.  I'm still working on it.

Comment: Digging through the net, I came across some pieces of information here and there. It seems this "broken pipe" error is thrown when the connection is killed by either end. Since SSL connections are expensive to initiate, I would guess that the Facebook SDK caches it. Then, the server (for some reason) decides to kill the connection but our Android client does not know about this until it tries to write data. Hence the error. I'm starting to think that a simple "retry once" logic would solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem which involves bypassing the Facebook SDK and doing the HTTP call yourself.  Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15260387/758458

Comment: Even though this might solve the problem, the SDK is still broken. We should register a bug so the Facebook team can fix it!